# Image consuming much more memory on Android 24

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-image

I have a quite big image that showing as a background in Splash screen. It's size on xxhdpi folder is 2.5 (Mb)

Here is my Splash screen code for testing

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
        logHeap()
    }

    private fun logHeap() {
        val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
        val maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory()
        val totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory()
        val freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory()
        val usedMemory: Long = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()
        val availableMemory = maxMemory - usedMemory
        Log.d("TAG", "maxMemory:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, maxMemory))
        Log.d("TAG", "totalMemory:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, totalMemory))
        Log.d("TAG", "freeMemory:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, freeMemory))
        Log.d("TAG", "usedMemory:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, usedMemory))
        Log.d("TAG", "availableMemory:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, availableMemory))
        Log.d("TAG", "density:" + resources.displayMetrics.density)
    }
}
```

When I run emulator `Pixel 3a API 12`, everything seem fine, `usedMemory` is **4.8 MB**

```
D/TAG: maxMemory:201 MB
D/TAG: totalMemory:201 MB
D/TAG: freeMemory:197 MB
D/TAG: usedMemory:4.8 MB
D/TAG: availableMemory:197 MB
D/TAG: density:2.75
```

But when I run on the same emulator with lower API `Pixel 3a API 24`, I get `usedMemory` **39 MB**. It's almost 8 times bigger

```
D/TAG: maxMemory:48 MB
D/TAG: totalMemory:42 MB
D/TAG: freeMemory:3.6 MB
D/TAG: usedMemory:39 MB
D/TAG: availableMemory:9.9 MB
D/TAG: density:2.75
```

This test is on a new empty application. In my real application, I also have many other objects in SplashScreen, then the `usedMemory` is almost `48 MB` and I get Out Of Memory error.
Either I set image to `activity_splash` or `windowBackground` (in the theme), the above result is same.

I can fix `Out Of Memory` on API 24 if I enable `android:largeHeap="true"` but it's seem not necessary for higher API. Also, I want to know why the same image take lot of memory.

Comment: What is the image size, image format (jpg, png), and color depth (8/16/24 bit)?

Comment: the image size is 2.54Mb (xxhdpi folder), in png format and 32-bit color

Comment: By image size I meant "what is the width x height". Also have you tried jpg format or reduced color?

Comment: my current image size is quite big 3000x3000 pixels
change image to jpg will save a lot of size (the new size in jpg is only 300kb) but the memory still same.
Also, I tried to reduce the image quality to very low but memory still same

Comment: @MorrisonChang I think this problem is relevant to the size (width/height) only, so I will change the design to use small icon for Splash screen (instead of a big picture), thanks for mention jpg, I will convert other pictures in my app to jpg to save app size